# gcloud API: example run.Service for deploying a container

Tags: go, gcloud

I wish to deploy the gcloud hello-world container via the gcloud API.

What is the correct `run.Service` spec to achieve this?

My current app is below however it fails with the error `googleapi: Error 404: Requested entity was not found.`

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    // "sort"
    // "google.golang.org/api/option"
    run "google.golang.org/api/run/v1alpha1"
)

const (
    createDefaultClientFlag = true
    scopes                  = run.CloudPlatformScope
    // List the Cloud Run services in this location
    serviceName = "test"
    locationsId = "us-central1"
    projectId   = "sql-manager-293118"
    imageName   = "gcr.io/cloudrun/hello"
)

func createDefaultClient(ctx context.Context) (*run.APIService, error) {
    return run.NewService(ctx)
}

func main() {
    // https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/run/v1#NewService
    var err error = nil
    var runService *run.APIService = nil

    ctx := context.Background()
    runService, err = createDefaultClient(ctx)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }

    projectsLocationsService := *run.NewProjectsLocationsService(runService)

    // Define the service to deploy
    tmpservice := &run.Service{
        ApiVersion: "serving.knative.dev/v1",
        Kind:       "Service",
        Metadata: &run.ObjectMeta{
            Name:      serviceName,
            Namespace: projectId,
        },
        Spec: &run.ServiceSpec{
            Template: &run.RevisionTemplate{
                Spec: &run.RevisionSpec{
                    Containers: []*run.Container{{
                        Image: imageName,
                    }},
                },
            },
        },
    }

    createCall := projectsLocationsService.Services.Create("projects/"+projectId+"/locations/"+locationsId, tmpservice)
    service, err := createCall.Do()
    fmt.Println(service, err)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error creating new locationservice: %s", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v", service.Spec)
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide in which line is the error being thrown and the full traceback? Also  [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/using-pure-golang-for-google-cloud-bacc6b62e0ed) might be helpful as it shows how to create Cloud Run services with the golang client library.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by changing `run "google.golang.org/api/run/v1alpha1"` to `run "google.golang.org/api/run/v1"`

Comment: Please post the working source code too for others' benefit. I assume you had to change the Go type and Kubernetes type too.

Comment: That was the only change needed.